# Problems to rotate the coordinates of my ship

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, sdl-2

I am doing the asteroids of Atari in C. When I use `rotate_coordinates()` the coordinates of the ship with a certain angle, the ship starts to rotate on its own axis with a speed; if I increase the angle, it increases the speed of this rotation.
I'm using the SDL2 libraries to make all the whole graphic part of the game.

I have the structure type `ship_t` where it has all the parameters of my ship:

```
typedef struct{    
    float x_pos;
    float y_pos;
    float vx;
    float vy;
    float angle;
    float power;
}ship_t;
```

Then, in the main I ask for memory for a pointer to ship_t, I create the ship with the initial coordinates.

```
ship_t *ship = malloc(sizeof(ship_t));
ship_new(ship);
```

Then the while begins, inside the cases of pressing the keys the functions receive a pointer to ship_t to be able to modify the angle and the power of the ship.

```
 case SDLK_RIGHT:                   
      ship_rotate_right(ship);
    //This returns ship->angle += (PI/20)
    break;
 case SDLK_LEFT:
    ship_rotate_left(ship);
    //This returns ship->angle -= (PI/20)
    break;
```

Then, during the while I'm calling a function that graph the ship:

```
ship_draw(ship);
```

Where ship_draw() is:

```
ship_draw(const ship_t *ship){
    plotter("SHIP", scale, ship->x_pos, ship->y_pos, ship->angle);
}
```

My function to plotter every sprite in the game is:

```
bool plotter(const *char name,float scale ,float x, float y, float angle){
    sprite_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(sprite_t));
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return false;
    // I have all the sprites on a list that previously load in dynamic memory.
    // I search the name of my sprite(in this case the SHIP) and then
    // I get the coordinates with the pointer ptr.
    ptr = list_search(lista_sprites,name,strcmp);
    //ptr->n is the length of the rows of the matrix that contains the coordinates of the SHIP
    rotate_coordinates(ptr->coords,ptr->n,angle);
    for(int i=0 ; i < ptr->n -1; i++)
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(
            renderer,
            ptr->coords[i][0] * scale + x,
            WINDOW_HIGH - (ptr->coords[i][1] * scale + y),
            ptr->coords[i+1][0] * scale +x ,
            WINDOW_HIGH - (ptr->coords[i+1][1] * scale + y)
        );

    return true;
}
```

I have my function to `rotate_coordinates()` which is like this:

```
void rotate_coordinates(float p[][2],size_t len,float angle){
    size_t i;
    float x_new,y_new;
    float calc_cos = cos(angle);
    float calc_sin = sin(angle);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        x_new = p[i][0]*calc_cos - p[i][1]*calc_sin;
        y_new = p[i][0]*calc_sin + p[i][1]*calc_cos;

        p[i][0] = x_new;
        p[i][1] = y_new;
    }   
}
```

The ship should rotate me only the step rotation that I give it that is PI / 20. But rotates on its axis. The same for the asteroids, they always rotate on their axis.

On the other hand, I need if or if I call the function `rotate_coordinates` within the plotter, since it is in this function where I obtain the coordinates of my ship from the dynamic memory.

Comment: Apart from anything else, can you use `double` instead of `float`?

Comment: out of your problem in _plotter_ you create a memory leak doing `sprite_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(sprite_t));` then `ptr = list_search(lista_sprites,name,strcmp);`, just do `sprite_t *ptr = list_search(lista_sprites,name,strcmp);` and perhaps check if you get or not NULL

Comment: @bruno Done!, thanks!

Comment: @WeatherVaneI could do it, but why would I be able to do it with double?

Comment: @ArturoAguilarLopez the floats are on 32bits, the double are on 64bits offering a better précision

Comment: What "they always rotate on their axis" means? It looks like you're constantly adding rotation on each frame with overwriting your `coords`. If that is your problem, it could be solved by calculating new coordinates to temporary variables before drawing without overwriting initial non-rotated coordinates.

Comment: @keltar I solved it with that idea, thank you very much.